# Volley callback to return a ArrayList and then send it to a RecyclerView.Adapter

Tags: android, callback, android-recyclerview, android-volley

I have an `Adapter` for a `RecyclerView`, my `Adapter` expect two parameter one is the `Context` and the second one is an `ArrayList`.

The `ArrayList` on my `MainActivity` looks something like this. I'm not able to return the ArrayList when the method onSucces finish.

```
ArrayList<Doc> docs = new ArrayList<> ();
public ArrayList<Doc>  getDocumentFromServer() {
    GetDocsFromServer.getAllDocs(getActivity(), new GetDocsFromServer.VolleyCallBackDocs(){
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ArrayList<String> documentos) {
            docs = new ArrayList<> ();
            for (int i = 0; i < documentos.size(); i++) {
                Doc item = new Doc ();
                item.setTittle("list item" + i);
                item.setDescription("DESCRIPTION");
                item.setPosition (i);
                docs.add(item);
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void onFail(String msg) {

        }
    });
    return docs;
}
```

When i declare `MyAdapter` on the `onCreateView` (It's a `Fragment`) seems something like this.

```
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), getDocumentFromServer());
```

By now i get all data from a DataBase with `Volley` and i set all this info into an `ArrayList`

```
public class GetOficiosFromServer{
public static void getAllWorks(final Context context, final VolleyCallBack callBack) {
    RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, AppConfig.URL_GET_WORKS, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray =  new JSONArray(response);
                ArrayList<String> oficios = new ArrayList<>();
                for(int i=0; i< jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String name = jsonObject.getString("nombre");
                    oficios.add(name);
                }
                callBack.onSuccess(oficios);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    });
    rq.add(strReq);
}
public interface VolleyCallBack{
    void onSuccess(ArrayList<String>oficios);
    void onFail(String msg);
}
```

How can i pass this `ArrayList<String>`into my `Adapter`.

Answer (score 0):

Write a constructor with `ArrayList<String>` as a parameter. Something like this

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    Context ctx;
    ArrayList<Doc> docs;
    ArrayList<String> officios;

    public MyAdapter(Context c,ArrayList<Doc> documents, ArrayList<String> offs){
      this.ctx = c;
      this.docs = documents;
      this.officios = offs
    }
}
```

You can pass the `ArrayList<String>` in your adapter initialization.

```
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), getDocumentFromServer(),<Your_array_list_here>);
```

Comment: I update my code from my MainActivity, the previous version was something static, y put the VolleyRequest insted. I'm not able to return the ArrayList when the method onSucces finish. @SripadRaj